# Is "Push [the opponent] to Game 7" a good or bad thing?

Tags: meaning

The Headline:

"[Rangers Push the Penguins to Game 7 in New York](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/05/14/sports/hockey/rangers-penguins-nhl-playoffs.html)"

I thought going to game 7 was a good thing, but based on the use of "push in" in the headline
and by reading the article I belive now game 7 is a bad thing. What am I getting wrong?
is game 7 good or is it bad?

Comment: Apparently New York Rangers are doing better than expected. They've ***pushed / forced*** their opponents Pittsburgh Penguins to have to play a ***seventh*** game, whereas normally the Penguins would have knocked Rangers out of the running after 6 games or less. Game 7 is thus good for Rangers because they don't usually get that far, but it's *bad* for the Penguins because they might have hoped to have won the series by now.  Dos that clarify things?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently New York Rangers are doing better than expected. They've pushed / forced their opponents Pittsburgh Penguins to have to play a seventh game, whereas normally the Penguins would have knocked Rangers out of the running after 6 games or less. Game 7 is thus good for Rangers because they don't usually get that far, but it's bad for the Penguins because they might have hoped to have won the series by now.